# Finding the coefficient of a function when given the answer

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the inverse problem for the following function in R.

```
x + 2 (C1 * y) + C1 * C1 * z = d2
```

I can currently enter `C1` and get `d2` but need to enter `d2` and get `C1`. The variables `x`, `y` and `z` are all known and never change.

I already have some known `C1` and `d2` values to use.

```
 C1     d2 
 5   0.000316
 0   0.000193
-5   0.000123
```

Is there an `R` function which will allow me to enter the function, previous results and a `d2` value and for it return the `C1` coefficient?

Comment: Algebra was invented more than 1,000 years ago to solve this type of problem.

Comment: @Andrie I'm sure it was. I also think that someone would have created a R package to help solve such problem.

Comment: Hmmm I guess you could try the [Chat[(http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for this kind of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a quadratic equation of the form:

```
(x - d2)*C1^0 + (2*y)*C1^1 + (z)*C1^2 = 0
```

You can solve quadratics (and in fact any polynomial equation) with the function `polyroot()` in R:

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 3

d <- 0

polyroot(c(x-d, 2*y, z))
[1] -0.3333333+0i -1.0000000+0i
```

(Which gives two solutions, as you would expect)

To solve for a range of input values, you need to put this into your favourite `apply` function, in this case `sapply()`:

```
d <- seq(0, 1, 0.2)

sapply(d, function(dd)polyroot(c(x-dd, 2*y, z)))

              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]           [,5]         [,6]
[1,] -0.3333333+0i -0.2450296+0i -0.1722534-0i -0.1088933-0i -0.05203037+0i  0.000000+0i
[2,] -1.0000000+0i -1.0883037+0i -1.1610799+0i -1.2244400+0i -1.28130296+0i -1.333333+0i
```

Comment: Thanks. :) I think I need to brush up on my algebra.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
d2 = x + 2 C1 y + C1^2 z
```

which you can rearrange to get

```
z C1^2 + 2 y C1 + x - d2 = 0
```

This is a [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) in C1, which you can solve either using the quadratic formula, or just by plugging it into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+z++c_1%5E2+%2B+2+y+c_1+%2B+x+-+d_2+%3D+0+for+c_1) to get

```
C1 = (-sqrt( d2 * z - x * z + y^2 ) - y) / z
```